# How do i modify :hover values after an animation has occurred and changed the font-size of an h1?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations

How do i modify :hover after an animation has occurred and changed the font-size of an h1?
it goes like this:
text: font-size: 12.5rem; letter-spacing: 0;
hover over the text- font-size: 13.5rem letter-spacing: 1rem; , after a few seconds, an animation with @keyframes comes and is changing the font-size, from 12.5rem to 5 rem. with the new change applied (font-size: 5rem;) I want to hover over it again but this time the values of :hover to change, the size when I hover to be from 5rem(the new values after the animation) to 6 rem, and letter-spacing, from 1rem; to 0.2rem.
i don't know how to do it.. please help me with some code

Comment: i think is impossible with vanilla css, but I will try to created with Vanilla js, i will put the answer then :)

Comment: i will try to help you, because no one gave you a answer, now i sended the answer

Comment: really appreciate, i like help :)

Comment: :))))))))))))))))) i know how it feels, thanks a lot again:))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## solution created with vanilla Js

```js
let title = document.getElementById('title');
let i = 0;

title.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    if (i >= 1) {
        hoverText(5, 6);
        title.removeEventListener('mouseover', function() {});
    } else {
        hoverText(12.5, 13.5);
        i++;
    }
});

function hoverText(small, big) {
    title.style.fontSize = big + "rem";
    setTimeout(function() {
        title.style.fontSize = small + "rem";
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
h1#title {
    font-size: 12.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="title">h1 element</h1>
</body>

</html>
```